# How to pass a block

Tags: ruby, yield

For the sake of simplicity, I've tried to abstract the problem down to its core elements. I've included a small piece of functionality wherein I use `Socket` to show that I want to pass the block further down into a method which is a black box for all intents and purposes. I'm also passing a constant `True` for the sake of showing I want to pass arguments as well as a yield block.

With all that being said, if I small have a hierarchy of calls as such:

```ruby
def foo(use_local_source)
  if use_local_source
    Socket.unix("/var/run/my.sock") &yield
  else
    Socket.tcp("my.remote.com",1234) &yield
  end
end

foo(True) { |socket|
  name = socket.read
  puts "Hi #{name}, I'm from foo."
}
```

How can I pass the implicitly declared block right down through `foo` and into `Socket` as if I were calling `Socket.tcp(...) { ... }` directly.

I know I could set it as an argument, but it doesn't feel idiomatic to Ruby. Is this also untrue and I should pass it as an argument? I've tried combinations of `&` and `*`, and I get a range of exception.

Comment: What is `True`? Don't put too many constants/methods without explaining. Assuming it is a constant, it is not clear why you are using such construct. Assuming it is a method, it is not clear at all what the code is doing.

Comment: Fair enough. True was just a token argument to show I had a function ```foo`` which took arguments as well as a yield.

Comment: @sawa I'll take most of the comments in regards to technicals on board, but I'd like to suggest you don't change the mood or writing style of people's questions. I prefer to write and read questions which are of an informal (yet, clear) manner. If I chose perfect instead of preterite tenses or emphatic replication, I've done it to explain my problem using the thought processes I have at that point in time rather than the thought processes I will have after the questions is answered, which is what someone else who was looking for the question would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo(use_local_source)
  if use_local_source
    yield Socket.unix("/var/run/my.sock")
  else
    yield Socket.tcp("my.remote.com",1234)
  end
end
```

From the docs for `yield`:

> Yields control back to the context that resumed the fiber, ***passing along any arguments that were passed to it***.

Comment: Ah brilliant! I did read through the yield docs and I remember reading that sentence, but to be frankly honest, did not understand what it meant without the example. To be truthful, I still don't. Am I passing the entirely of ```Socket.unix("/var/run/my.sock")``` as an argument to yield?

Comment: (and I've tried it in my code and it works perfectly)

Comment: Yes, you are passing arguments just like you would in any other method.  The mental oddity is that you're passing them back to the block ("anonymous function" if that helps) that called it in the first place.  See https://gist.github.com/phallstrom/83e3b7f09cd0f9508793 and pay attention to the subtle differences between the two methods, but the same result.

Comment: OK,  thank you. I think I get it now. That little gist clears it up. I started cutting my teeth on ruby about a week ago, so this has cleared up a (what  think), a core piece of functionality in Ruby.